# Fractions, solve to simpliest form

Tags: math, fractions

I'm having trouble solving this expression:

```
(x - 1)(7x + 6)        7
----------------- + -------
(x - 1)(x + 1)^2    (x + 1)
```

What's the steps to solve this?

I know you expand (x + 1)^2 to (x + 1)(x + 1) and that you need to find a common denominator before adding the numerators together.

Thanks.

Comment: better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
           (x-1)(7x+6)(x+1) + 7(x-1)(x+1)^2   14x+13
          -------------------------------- = ---------
           (x - 1)(x + 1)^3                   (x+1)^2
```

The common denominator is found by multiplying the denominators of the question.  That is `(x-1)(x+1)^2 * (x+1)`.  You then multiply `(x-1)(7x+6)` with `(x+1)` and `7` by `(x-1)(x+1)^2` and add them to obtain the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Since (x-1) is on both the numerator and the denominator of the first fraction, remove those:

```
(7x + 6)        7
---------- + -------
(x + 1)^2    (x + 1)
```

Next, (x + 1)^2 equals (x + 1)(x + 1).  This tells you to multiple (x + 1) to your right hand fraction:

```
(7x + 6)            7(x + 1)
--------------- + --------------
(x + 1)(x + 1)    (x + 1)(x + 1)
```

No that you have a common denominator, add your numerators together:

```
(7x + 6) + 7(x + 1) = (7x + 6) + (7x + 7) = 14x + 13
```

So your final result looks like this:

```
14x + 13           14x + 13
-------------- = --------------
(x + 1)(x + 1)     (x + 1)^2
```

Hope this helps -- good luck!

Comment: You got one step wrong - `7(x+1)` = `7x + 7`, not `7x + 1`

Comment: The final answer is


'
     -1
------------
x^2 + 2x + 1
'

Comment: Thanks @DStanley -- just edited -- didn't see that :)